# jQuery: Set cookie for two domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I want to set a cookie to a domain, but it should be available for a sub domain as well.

e.g. www.mydomain.com and sub.mydomain.com

When I set the cookie to the main domain it doesn't exist for the subdomain.

I use jQuery cookie Plugin: 
https://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation

My idea was to store it for both domains, have a look at the code:

```
var newOptions = {
    domain: 'sub.mydomain.com',
    secure: true
}
jaaulde.utils.cookies.set('name', 'value');
jaaulde.utils.cookies.set('name', 'value', newOptions );
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Cash2m is correct, you should be able to specify a . to reach your subdomains:

```
$.cookie('key', 'value', { domain: '.mydomain.com' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to extend it to the domain and not only a specific subdomain, just use

```
domain : 'mydomain.com'
```

instead of :

```
domain: 'sub.mydomain.com'
```

Comment: I think you meant `domain : '.mydomain.com'`

Comment: No I didn't... It should work that way, the starting point has no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I did change the domain to mydomain.com but I still get undefined when I try to get the cookie